# latex + hyperref + glossaries + pstricks produces colored text and underlined links in DVI though neither is commanded

Tags: hyperref, pstricks, glossaries, dvi, dvi-mode

Feeding mwe.tex containing

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}%%% The documentation of glossaries tells to load hyperref first.
\usepackage[style=long3colheader,toc]{glossaries}% using v4.52
\usepackage{pstricks}
\makeglossaries
\newglossaryentry{productOrder}{name={product order}, text={\sqsubseteq}, sort=productOrder, description={Given posets $(X_i,{\le_i})$ and $n\in\mathbb{N}_0$, the \emph{product order} on $L=\prod_{i=1}^n X_i$ is defined by $(a_i)_{i=1}^n\sqsubseteq (b_i)_{i=1}^n$ iff $\forall\mskip3mu plus1.5mu minus1.5mu i\in\mathbb{N}_n: a_i\le_i b_i$ ($(a_i)_{i=1}^n, (b_i)_{i=1}^n\in L$).}, user1={\not{\sqsubseteq}}}
\begin{document}
Consider the lattice $L=\prod_{i=1}^n \mathfrak{P}(D_i)$, which we equip with a product order $\gls{productOrder}$ $=$ $\{((X_i)_{i=1}^n,(X_i')_{i=1}^n)\in L^2\mid \forall\mskip3mu plus1.5mu minus1.5mu i\in\mathbb{N}_n\colon X_i\subseteq X_i'\}$ and the least element $\bot=(\emptyset)_{i=1}^n$.
\printglossary
\end{document}
```

to `latex mwe && makeglossaries mwe && latex mwe && makeglossaries mwe && latex mwe` yields the following DVI output, as shown by xdvi:

[image: DVI output, viewed in xdvi]

Despite `hidelinks`, the two links (⊑ in the main text and the page number 1 in the page list) are underlined, and there's lots of blue color where none was commanded.  Who is the culprit and what to do?  To be fair, `dvips` and `dvipdf -dALLOWPSTRANSPARENCY` (where `dvipdf` is [taken from Ghostscript](http://sources.debian.org/src/ghostscript/9.53.3%7Edfsg-7+deb11u4/lib/dvipdf)) straighten things out for Postscript and PDF, but still, the DVI output itself is bad where it needn't be ***THAT*** bad. There are no images to be displayed and, except links, which are told to be hidden anyway, this example exhibits no special features that couldn't be represented in DVI.

Comment: You are inserting lots of \special's meant for dvips, if your dvi misinterprete them there is nothing the LaTeX code can do, check the settings of you dvi viewer, perhaps it can render as ps.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer From a user's viewpoint, there are no `\special`s in the document. The viewer used in the original post is xdvi. (If you take okular, the output seems fine.)

Comment: add \showoutput to your code and then check the log-file and you will see lots of specials. And I don't know xdvi, so can't tell you if it has some option to improve the handling.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Yes; no argument concerning `\showoutput`.

Comment: And as a side remark: hidelinks only sets the pdfborder to zero, that is only relevant for the PDF export,  everything from a link is still there.

Comment: oh sorry I forgot about that one, that's  a simple shell script which calls dvips then gs so ignore my comment (which I will delete)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Got it. Thanks! Now we may get rid of our last two comments to keep the post clean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the "problem" is this last line of `pstricks.tex`:

```
\pstVerb{0.8 setlinewidth 0 setgray}%
```

which is only needed if PSTricks is used with lualatex. I suppose that it confuses the color handling of dvi. Using

```
\ifluatex\pstVerb{0.8 setlinewidth 0 setgray}\fi
```

needs some testing.

[image]

Use this order of packages:

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[style=long3colheader,toc]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries
```

However, you shouldn't use a dvi viewer, using the pdf output, created with lualatex, makes more sense.

Comment: For test purposes, I changed pstricks.tex as you said for compiling a way larger document, which uses pst-all. I observed no changes in the final results of the DVI→[via dvipdf] PDF and DVI→[via dvips] PS→[via ps2pdf] PDF toolchains. I also observed no visible changes in the DVI output directly (but I couldn't compare all dozens of pages manually). (For my large document, the DVI output looks now fine without your bugfix for reasons unknown to me, so my test doesn't mean too much, and further testing might be necessary.) Summarizing, your bug fix looks fine to me.

Comment: @AlMa0:  I uploaded the wrong image. Now the second line is correct

Comment: Thanks! Your change probably also fixes https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/684378/pstricks-causes-the-output-of-xdvi-turning-gray , when combined with http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/684378/pstricks-causes-the-output-of-xdvi-turning-gray#comment1698019_684378 . Can you confirm or reject this and if the fix is correct, push it upstream or suggest pushing it upstream?