# pstricks causes the output of xdvi to turn gray

Tags: pstricks, ghostscript, xdvi

Feed mwe.tex containing

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\begin{document}
Test
\end{document}
```

to `latex`, then issue `xdvi mwe` from an xterm under X11+gnome, and finally observe

[image: output]

On the console,

```
gs: 
gs: %%%% WARNING: Transparency operations ignored - need to use -dALLOWPSTRANSPARENCY
gs: 
gs:
```

is printed.

This is strange. The input file has no transparency whatsoever. In fact, pstricks is only loaded but never used in the input document.  Further, there's IMHO no way for xdvi to pass the option `-dALLOWPSTRANSPARENCY` to gs. Finally, the graphical output “Test” should be black and not gray.

Presumably, updating texlive-binaries, texlive-pstricks, or ghostscript might solve the problem, but which versions of which packages would be the smallest to have the fix?  Versions used in this question:

- Debian package texlive 2022.20221123-1,
- Debian package texlive-binaries 2022.20220321.62855-4+b1,
- Debian package ghostscript 9.53.3~dfsg-7+deb11u4,
- `latex` has version `pdfTeX 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.24 (TeX Live 2022/Debian)`,
- `xdvi` has version 22.87.06,
- `pstricks.sty` has version 2022/19/23 v0.72, and
- `gs` has version 9.53.3.

I don't wish to update the machine in this very question myself without being well advised because this might trigger newer bugs, and rollbacks sometimes failed in the past. I would update the machine in question rather conservatively and upon advice.

EDIT: The issues seem to be fixed by the combination of http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/684283 and [pstricks causes the output of xdvi turning gray](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/684378/pstricks-causes-the-output-of-xdvi-turning-gray#comment1698019_684378) .  Therefore, the final bugfix is probably still expected to happen upstream in some way.

Comment: you can set the gs option via `xdvi -interpreter ./gsx file` where `gsx` is a shell script `gs -dALLOWPSTRANSPARENCY $*`  but Test is still grey

Comment: Why don't you convert to ps or pdf and use a ps or pdf viewer if you want a reliable output?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I tried your script and it happened as you said. The issues seem to be solvable by the combination of your comment http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/684378/pstricks-causes-the-output-of-xdvi-turning-gray#comment1698019_684378 and http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/684283 .  Can you confirm or reject this on your side?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I use the DVI output for debugging purposes, namely, if the Postscript or PDF output is unexpected and does not immediately follow from the source document. This doesn't happen often but it does happen.

Comment: I cleaned up comments a bit following the posted answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the current version 3.19 of PSTricks, available for TeXLive and MiKTeX both should be fixed.

- the message with ALLOWPSTRANSPARENCY was a problem with `pstricks.pro`
- text in gray a problem with `pstricks.tex`

Comment: Thanks! Will it be pushed to TeXLive 2023 soon? Issuing `grep -hr "[\\]ProvidesPackage" ~/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pstricks` yields `\ProvidesPackage{pstcol}
\ProvidesPackage{pst-all}[2008/01/01 the main pstricks tools]
\ProvidesPackage{pstricks}[2022/19/23 v0.72 LaTeX wrapper for \`PSTricks' (RN,HV)]
\ProvidesPackage{pstricks-pdf}[2020/06/11 v0.02 creating pdf output (hv)]
\ProvidesPackage{pst-key}[2004/07/15 package wrapper for pst-key.tex]`. I don't see any version number near 3.19, but I might be looking in the wrong place.

Comment: run the update manager of TL or MiKTeX and PSTricks should be updated. Maybe that your mirror needs some time to refresh

Comment: Have just done so. If you refer to texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/pstricks.tex, TeXLive 2023 still has version 3.18 from 2022-11-28: `$ tlmgr update --all`  “says no updates available”, and the output of `grep "[\\]fileversion{" ~/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/pstricks.tex` is `\def\fileversion{3.18}`.

Comment: Then your PSTricks was not updated. As I wrote, it depends to your mirror, if the the new version is available after one or two days. And did you run `tlmgr`?

Comment: Alright, thanks! Yes, I ran `tlmgr update --all`.

Comment: I have an alias `tlupdate` for `tlmgr --self --all  update` and got.  `bash-3.2$ tlupdate
tlmgr: package repository https://ctan.kako-dev.de/systems/texlive/tlnet (not verified: gpg unavailable)
tlmgr: no self-updates for tlmgr available
[1/2, ??:??/??:??] update: pstricks [7563k] (65346 -> 66973) ... done
[2/2, 00:12/00:12] update: texlive-scripts [528k] (66964 -> 66972) ... done`

Comment: Now, the update has finally propagated, and the issue is resolved. Thanks!